# Tkinter objects are not centering

Tags: python-3.x, oop, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create a simple Python 3.x GUI project with tkinter, just to learn the language better (I started learning Python not long ago), of which the only thing it does is switching between different pages as a button is clicked. The problem is that the objects are not getting in the center of the screen. What's wrong in my code?

Images:

[Start Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Twpa.png)

[First Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwhFl.png)

[Second Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ra9K2.png)

```
import tkinter as tk

LARGE_FONT = ("verdana", 10)


class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.grid()

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="snew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage (tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button1.grid(row=1, column=0)

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page Two",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.grid(row=2, column=0)


class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label2 = tk.Label(self, text="Page One", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="E")

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page Two",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.grid(row=1, column=0)

        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Start Page",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button3.grid(row=2, column=0)


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label2 = tk.Label(self, text="Page Two", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label2.grid(row=0, column=0,sticky="E")

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button2.grid(row=1, column=0)

        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Start Page",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button3.grid(row=2, column=0)


app = Application()
app.title("Application")
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're starting with too complex of an example. I recommend you start by creating a program that only has a single page. Get that working before you try to juggle multiple pages at once.

Comment: Thank you for replying! I actually already made some simple projects before with only one page and I feel ready to try something a little bit harder. I understand the basics of OOP and tkinter so I started this new project that I saw in a youtube tutorial but I still couldn't solve the centralization problem, is it really difficult to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I put a menu on the left with tkinter. Everything to the right of the menu is aligned in the middle. How to align to the right of the menu

There is a text on the back of the textbox, but because it is center-aligned, it crosses over the text and the text does not appear.

[Tkinter program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/founX.png)

All code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter.font as font
import tkinter as tkMessageBox
from typing import Sized
from PIL import ImageTk, Image  

window = Tk()
window.title("Ogretmen+")
window.geometry("900x447")
window.configure(bg="#202020")

genelgorunumbaslik = font.Font(size=20)
menuyazilar = font.Font(size=20)
guncellemebuyuk = font.Font(size=15)

def sinifYonetimi():
    sinifyonetimiaciklama.config(text="Sınıf yönetimi kısmına hoş geldiniz. Bu bölümden sınıf ekleyebilir ve silebilirsiniz. Örnek sınıf adı: 10 B")
    sinifyonetimiaciklama.grid(row=1, column=2)

    sinifadigir.config(text="Sınıf Adı:")
    sinifadigir.grid(row=2, column=2)
    sinifadientry.grid(row=2, column=2)
    islemsec.grid_remove()

sinifyonetimiaciklama = Label(fg="white", bg="#202020")
sinifadigir = Label(fg="white", bg="#202020")
sinifadientry = Entry(bd=4)

menubuton2 = Button(text="Sınıf Yönetimi", fg="white", bg="#282528", height=3, command=sinifYonetimi)
menubuton3 = Button(text="Öğrenci Yönetimi", fg="white", bg="#282528", height=3)
menubuton4 = Button(text="Konu Takibi", fg="white", bg="#282528", height=3)
menubuton5 = Button(text="İletişim", fg="white", bg="#282528", height=2)

menubuton2['font'] = menuyazilar
menubuton3['font'] = menuyazilar
menubuton4['font'] = menuyazilar
menubuton5['font'] = menuyazilar


menubuton2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="ew")
menubuton3.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="ew")
menubuton4.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="ew")
menubuton5.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky="ew")

islemsec = Label(text="Lütfen sol menüden işlem seçiniz.", bg="#202020", fg="white")
islemsec.grid(row=1, column=3)

window.mainloop()
```